# jquery - set div as not required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 3 different options (artigo, revista, livro)

Each one has a unique form, some with required fields others not

I have to choose only one option, fill the respective form and submit. 
The problem is that it doesnt let me submit because there are others required fields in the other divs.

What I want is if I select `tipo_artigo1` it sets `tipo_livro` as not required so I can finally submit the final form.

I already have this code

```
<script>
    $(".js-select2").each(function(){
        $(this).select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: 20,
            dropdownParent: $(this).next('.dropDownSelect2')
        });

        $(".js-select2").each(function(){
            $(this).on('select2:close', function (e){
                if($(this).val() == "tipo_artigo1") {
                    $('.tipo_artigo').slideDown();
                    $('.tipo_livro').slideUp();
                    $('.tipo_revista').slideUp();
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "tipo_revista2"){
                    $('.tipo_artigo').slideUp();
                    $('.tipo_livro').slideUp();
                    $('.tipo_revista').slideDown(); 
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "tipo_livro3"){
                    $('.tipo_artigo').slideUp();
                    $('.tipo_revista').slideUp();
                    $('.tipo_livro').slideDown();   
                }
            });
        });
    })  
</script>
```

Hopefully, I explained explicitly. Sorry for any grammatical mistakes

Comment: Could you please share your html as well and even better provide a working example via jsfiddle or others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `required` attribute of an element thanks to [`$.fn.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
if ($(this).val() == "tipo_artigo1") {
    // other code

    // Unrequires all <.tipo_livro> elements.
    $('.tipo_livro').prop('required', false);
}
```

But since `.tipo_livro` is a `<div>`:

```
if ($(this).val() == "tipo_artigo1") {
    // other code

    // Unrequires all <div.tipo_livro> sub-elements which are required.
    $('.tipo_livro').find('[required]').prop('required', false);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id's of the fields you want to mark as not required, you can use :

```
$('#input_field').removeAttr('required');
```